# Build in a linux container fails to find gtest (using vcpkg and CMake)

Tags: cmake, continuous-integration, dockerfile, vcpkg

I've tried build a project in a container and have some very (simple?) problem.
I have a couple of unit tests that use gtest and chose to use vcpkg to build it since I aim to target windows/linux machines.

When I build on my or someone else's computer everything seem to work, but when I build the project in the container it fails to find the include files for gtest.
Is there anything I missed in the CMake integration with vcpkg that needs to be done for my project?

My current state is that I start the container and use an interactive shell to manually build everything inside it (so I can try debug the issue).

Here is my Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Needed to be set for the cmake package to be installed properly without interactive input
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install gcc-10 -y
RUN apt-get install g++-10 -y

# Set gcc/g++ so they default to the installed versions
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 1
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 1
RUN apt-get install cmake -y

# zip / pkg-config were required for vcpkg to build some dependencies
RUN apt-get install zip -y
RUN apt-get install pkg-config -y

# below are convenience for opening a shell terminal in the docker image
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
# enables tab-completion and some colors
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/1.29.2/contrib/completion/bash/docker-compose -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose

# copy local files to be built
COPY scripts /build/scripts
COPY src /build/src
COPY CMakeLists.txt /build
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg)
    message( FATAL_ERROR
        "Clone vcpkg at ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\n"
        "cd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\n"
        "git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git --depth 1\n"
        "cd vcpkg\n"
        "./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh"
        "./vcpkg install gtest:x64-linux"
        )
endif()

if (WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64) # Force 64 bits
elseif (LINUX)
    set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-linux")
endif()

# Setup vcpkg toolchain
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/runtime)

if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
endif()

project(TheProject)

find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    "src/cpp"
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

EDIT: If I hardcode the include paths / library paths to point to the vcpkg installed directory in the CMakeLists.txt everything works, but I thought it should only be necessary to setup the toolchain file for it to work.
The unmodified toolchain-integration works like a charm outside any container (on a computer).

How can I avoid this hack? It will not scale at all later on.

Below is the hack that make everything work (not needed on a computer):

```cmake
include_directories(
        "src/cpp"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include"
)

link_directories(
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib"
)
```

Comment: a) what is the error?  
b) how does the CMakeLists.txt in src look?

Comment: case closed. Thanks for the comment I missed a line which was specialized for windows and forgot to translate it to linux... shame on me.